# Determining the limits of an integral

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, optics

In Griffiths' *Introduction to Electrodynamics*, Problem 1.28 (the triangular prism question) is especially challenging for me. I do not know how the limits of x are **0** to (**1-y**). 
My concern is the latter limit, **1-y**. Can you explain systemically how this is arrived at?
On the face of it, I'm inclined to say the limits of x are **0** and **1**. I can see it's the diagonal across the x- and y-axes that's presenting the extra challenge, but I do not know how to go about establishing that indeed the limit is **1-y**.

Comment: It would be good if OP (or somebody else?) could try to make the question formulation self-contained, so one doesn't have to open Griffiths' book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the problem specifically, but I can easily imagine how 1-y came up.

Just try to draw a prism using the three points (0,0), (0,1) and (1,0) on the xy-plane. Now try to figure out the linear equation that governs the line between (0,1) and (1,0), and you'll see that the line's equation is $x=1-y$.

By doing a surface integral on surface that is limited by the points I mentioned, and the integral will be (in the simplest case for calculating the area):

$$\iint_S dS = \int_0^1dy\int_0^{1-y}dx$$

I hope this helps.